# Apex Callout Exception: IO Exception: Read timed out

Tags: apex, callout, exception, future

I have Salesforce trigger that triggers either a future method or batch job that does call outs to a SOAP webservice. IF the number of call outs I need to make is one then future method is triggered. Or if There are more than one call outs need to be done I call a batch job and it does call outs.

I am randomly getting "(IO Exception: Read timed out)" exception. When the timeout issue started happening today I also received 2 other exceptions:

(IO Exception: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable")

(Web service callout failed: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Envelope' but found ':h1').

The webservice works most of the time fine but the timeout issue happens randomly.

When the timeout issue happens, I try a sample request using WCF Test Client and it times out as well.

When I talked to the guys on the external system side when the time out issue was happening, they are saying they cannot even see the request coming  and  there are more than open connections at that moment from our salesforce IP. When they kill the connections, it starts responding again.

I have no idea why it is happening.

Any Help is appreciated 
Duygu

Comment: have you tried setting request timeout to maximum time. (120000 secs).

Comment: I would look into if this is a firewall issue - is there something between internet and the web service server.